# Partner object - workbench says it's triggerable - but it's not

Tags: trigger, partner

I need to create a trigger on the OpportunityPartner object. I know it's not triggerable.

However, looking with workbench on the 'Partner' object, it's triggerable attribute is 'True'

Is that a mistake?

I still can't have a trigger on the 'Partner' object either.

[image]

Comment: Note that updateable and undeletable are both false. I'd expect you can only have a before insert and a before delete trigger on the object since deletable is also true. What kind of trigger were you trying to write?

Comment: I tried for any of these, I get the same error: Sobject type does not allow... But why does the attribute says it's True???

Comment: Looks like it could be a bug. I've reached out to the owners of the Partner type inside SF and will let you know what I find out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I talked to the team that owns the Partner SObject definition and they confirmed that it does not support Apex triggers.

I've logged a bug internally (W-5266695) for them to investigate correcting the erroneous describe information.

Comment: Thanks. Now if only this object were 'Triggerable'.........  :-)